# Verifying Spark SASL Encryption for RPC

Tags: apache-spark

I set spark.authenticate.enableSaslEncryption to true and want to verify that the RPC is encrypted.

1. I want to check that the feature is enabled. Would I find such a message in the logs?
2. If I wanted to make sure the packets were encrypted, would I do a tcpdump and inspect the packets to confirm that the information is *not* in plaintext?

I'm pretty new to Spark so I do apologize if these are simple questions.

Comment: Could you please clarify what degree of verification you are looking for? For example, do you just want a log message to confirm that the feature appears to be turned on? Or do you want to inspect the RPC network traffic to confirm that information is not visible in plaintext?

Comment: I would like a log message to confirm that the feature appears to be turned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first step, if you add the `--verbose` flag to your `spark-submit` command, then Spark will print out the configuration settings, and you will see:

```
(spark.authenticate.enableSaslEncryption, true)
```

Next, you can enable `DEBUG` logging (via a `log4j.properties` file - see the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#configuring-logging)) and search the logs for entries mentioning Sasl.

With SASL Encryption enabled, you will see logging from classes including:

- SaslRpcClient
- TSaslTransport
- SparkSaslServer
- SaslRpcHandler

for example:

```
SparkSaslServer: SASL Authorization complete, authorized set to true

SaslRpcHandler: SASL authentication successful for channel TransportClient{...}
```